# Dictionary n: n*n, n+1: n+1*n+1

Tags: python, dictionary

Having trouble creating a dictionary that loops in term of n: n*n, n+1: n+1*n+1, and so on. It has to contain numbers between 1 and 10 in this form.

```
d = dict ()
for n in range (1,10): dict[n*n]
```

I cannot print the expected output. I have tried with `{}` as well to make it cleaner with no success (`n:n*n, n+1: n+1*n+1,...`).

I want to then be able to switch it up and learn how to use the different variables.

Comment: And what would be your expected output?*

Comment: Could you please add what your expected output is, it is hard to tell from your description. What key/values do you expect to have in your dict?

Comment: This: n: n*n, n+1: n+1*n+1, ...
Thanks!

Comment: `{n: n*n for n in range(10)}` ?

Comment: @Benoît has a good point. range(a, b) returns a range object that includes a, ***but not b***

Answer (score 10):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
{ n: n*n for n in range(10) }
```

It works like list comprehension, but the result is a dict.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
d = dict ()
for n in range (1,10):
    d[n] = n*n
```

or in one line:

```
d = {n: n*n for n in range(10)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `10` is not in `range(1, 10)`

If you want

```
{1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
```

You should use `{n: n*n for n in range(1, 11)}`

**Second part of the question:**

To do it with different values you can simply do:

```
{n: n*n for n in (1, 42, 274)} # {1: 1, 42: 1764, 274: 75076}

l = [3, 14, 15, 92, 65, 35]
d = {n: n*n for n in l} # {3: 9, 14: 196, 15: 225, 92: 8464, 65: 4225, 35: 1225}
v = d[92] # 8464
```